# How to implement domain method which creates another domain entity in a testable way

Tags: tdd, domain-driven-design, factory, creation

Option 1. In `ParentTest.CreateChild()` it's essentially testing `Child` constructor as well (which I don't like).

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public void CreateChild(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Child = new Child(param1, param2);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Param1 { get; private set; }
    public string Param2 { get; private set; }

    public Child(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Param1 = param1;
        Param2 = param2;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ParentTest
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateChild()
    {
        const int param1 = 23;
        const string param2 = "param2";
        var parent = new Parent();

        parent.CreateChild(param1, param2);

        Assert.That(parent.Child, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(parent.Child.Param1, Is.EqualTo(param1));
        Assert.That(parent.Child.Param2, Is.EqualTo(param2));
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ChildTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Create()
    {
        const int param1 = 23;
        const string param2 = "param2";

        var child = new Child(param1, param2);

        Assert.That(child.Param1, Is.EqualTo(param1));
        Assert.That(child.Param2, Is.EqualTo(param2));            
    }
}
```

Option 2. Uses a factory service to create `Child` instance. Here I'm not too sure about the idea of passing a service as a domain method parameter.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public void CreateChild(int param1, string param2, IChildFactory childFactory)
    {
        Child = childFactory.Create(param1, param2);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Param1 { get; private set; }
    public string Param2 { get; private set; }

    protected Child() {} // to be able to generate stub

    public Child(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Param1 = param1;
        Param2 = param2;
    }
}

public interface IChildFactory
{
    Child Create(int param1, string param2);
}

public class ChildFactory : IChildFactory
{
    public Child Create(int param1, string param2)
    {
        return new Child(param1, param2);
    }
}     

[TestFixture]
public class ParentTest
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateChild()
    {
        const int param1 = 23;
        const string param2 = "param2";
        var child = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Child>();
        var childFactory = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IChildFactory>();
        childFactory.Stub(x => x.Create(param1, param2)).Return(child);
        var parent = new Parent();

        parent.CreateChild(param1, param2, childFactory);

        Assert.That(parent.Child, Is.SameAs(child));
    }    
}

[TestFixture]
public class ChildTest
{
    // empty as contructor is tested in ChildFactoryTest
}

[TestFixture]
public class ChildFactoryTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Create()
    {
        const int param1 = 23;
        const string param2 = "param2";
        var childFactory = new ChildFactory();

        var child = childFactory.Create(param1, param2);

        Assert.That(child.Param1, Is.EqualTo(param1));
        Assert.That(child.Param2, Is.EqualTo(param2));
    }
}
```

I actually prefer option 2, as every time a domain method creates another domain entity, I don't have to test properties of created entity (those are tested only once in the factory test).

Anybody has better solution?

**Update:**
From @user1494736 answer: *"I think that if you are testing Parent, you should also test the Child constructor as well"*. You might have another method of `Parent` creating `Child`, and in its test you would need to test `Child` properties again. In general, I don't want to be testing result of `Child` constructor each time `Parent` method calls it. Let's suppose that `Child` constructor does some complex calculation from constructor parameters. You would have couple of tests for `Child` constructor alone just to test various combinations and results. Now, if you would be testing `Child` constructor in `Parent` test(s), and you would modify `Child` constructor implementation, these `Parent` test would start failing (thing I don't like and the main reason why I prefer option 2 even though I have some reservations with it too)

Answer (score 2):

You could modify option 2 to pass the `ChildFactory` in to `Parent`'s constructor instead of passing it as a parameter to `CreateChild()`:

```
public class Parent
{
    private IChildFactory _childFactory;

    public Parent(IChildFactory childFactory)
    {
        _childFactory = childFactory;
    }

    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public void CreateChild(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Child = _childFactory.Create(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I consider this as the same as option 2. You are calling a service method from domain method (a thing I'm not sure should be done). In general I feel it should be the other way around - a service method getting a domain entity as a parameter and calling its domain methods.

Comment: Sounds as though CreateChild isn't in the right place, then.  Maybe you should create a ChildRepository or a Domain Service.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the creation and make the method virtual:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public void CreateChild(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Child = new ObtainChild(param1, param2);
    }
    virtual public Child ObtainChild(int param1, string param2)
    {
        return new Child(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

And then create a "Testable" subclass with a different implementation, and test that one:
public class TestableParent : Parent
{
        override public Child ObtainChild(int param1, string param2)
        {
            //Do whatever you want here
        }
}

or:

public class TestableParent : Parent
{
        Func ObtainChildImplementation;
        override public Child ObtainChild(int param1, string param2)
        {
            return ObtainChildImplementation();
        }
}

Note that making Child implement an IChild interface and working with that will make things easier...

Alternative, you can achieve the same effect without the "Testable" class just by using a mocking framework which can handle this such as Moq:
var testableParent = new Mock(/* you can put Parents parameters here*/);
testableParent.Setup(parent => parent.ObtainChild(/* match parameters*/).Returns(/* return something*/);

BTW: I personally think White Box Testing is a very bad idea... And since most unit tests are white box tests, I generally think that most unit tests are also a bad idea... I think the best tests are functional black box tests, or integration tests, or whatever you want to call them... I think that if you are testing Parent, you should also test the Child constructor as well. I see that as a good thing, not as a bad thing... But if you really want to do it...

**Update:** If you change *only* the implementation of Child, but you don't change what it does, then the tests of Parent won't break if you have done functional tests. Additionally, if you have Parent tests that you can do whatever you want with Child, and don't break because you have mocked Child in all places, how the hell do you know that Parent uses Child correctly? In my experience most of the bugs, and the most difficult ones are most often found when integrating two components, because one assumes something is done in one reasonable way, and the other one in another reasonable way too (but a different one). I think that you should test the integration (and functionality) as most as you can.
Regarding the issue of having to test the properties of Child once and again, what you are saying, feels like you have duplicated code, which can be avoided if you refactor your tests, or create the proper abstractions you'll need in them.

Comment: I added my comment for this answer into the question text as it explains in more details option 1.